# Handling multiple callbacks to a route in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I read [the Express.js documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), and it talks about handling callbacks to routes with a syntax like:

```
app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

However, I cannot seem to find a good example of syntax for handling multiple callbacks of the catch-all `*` route.  Specifically, The route handler needs to:

1.) serve all requests for views with `index.html`, but then
2.) serve callback requests for assets specified in `index.html` by returning the appropriate file.

**What specific syntax is required to accomplish manage all the callbacks so that the Express.js server returns every requested resource file, including JavaScript, css, etc?**

When I use the following:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside * route!');           
    if(req.accepts('html')){
        console.log('req.accepts html');
        console.log('req.url is: '+ req.url);
    }
    if(req.accepts('text/html')){
        console.log('req.accepts text/html');
        console.log('req.url is: ' + req.url);
    }
    if(req.accepts('application/json')){
        console.log('req.accepts application/json');
        console.log('req.url is: ' + req.url);
    }
    if(req.accepts('json', 'text')){
        console.log('req.accepts json, text');
        console.log('req.url is: ' + req.url);
    }
    if(req.accepts('text/javascript')){
        console.log('req.accepts html');
        console.log('req.url is: ' + req.url);
    }
    if(req.accepts('text/css')){
        console.log('req.accepts text/css');
        console.log('req.url is: ' + req.url);
    }
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/client/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
});
```

The result is:

1.) `index.html` is served in response to every request for every file type, including JavaScript, css, etc.
2.) The conditional statements do not distinguish between content types of the requested file.

The console print out to document this is:

```
App listening on port 8080

inside * route!
req.accepts html
req.url is: /
req.accepts text/html
req.url is: /
req.accepts application/json
req.url is: /
req.accepts json, text
req.url is: /
req.accepts html
req.url is: /
req.accepts text/css
req.url is: /
GET / 304 30.181 ms - -

inside * route!
req.accepts html
req.url is: /boot.css
req.accepts text/html
req.url is: /boot.css
req.accepts application/json
req.url is: /boot.css
req.accepts json, text
req.url is: /boot.css
req.accepts html
req.url is: /boot.css
req.accepts text/css
req.url is: /boot.css

inside * route!
req.accepts html
req.url is: /vendor.js
req.accepts text/html
req.url is: /vendor.js
req.accepts application/json
req.url is: /vendor.js
req.accepts json, text
req.url is: /vendor.js
req.accepts html
req.url is: /vendor.js
req.accepts text/css
req.url is: /vendor.js

inside * route!
req.accepts html
req.url is: /boot.js
req.accepts text/html
req.url is: /boot.js
req.accepts application/json
req.url is: /boot.js
req.accepts json, text
req.url is: /boot.js
req.accepts html
req.url is: /boot.js
req.accepts text/css
req.url is: /boot.js
GET /boot.css 304 2.213 ms - -
GET /vendor.js 304 2.886 ms - -
GET /boot.js 304 2.638 ms - -
```

For reference, the root `index.html` for the Express.js app is:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/client'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

// load the routes
require('./router')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be accomplished using [static files serving](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

As stated in the official docs, you can just use the following code, to serve all assets (`.js`, `.css`, etc..):

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a static resource you're requiring from index.html?